# Converting RTF response to angular view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below is the RTF response which I'll receive from remote server.

```
"rjf":[
   {
      "type":"paragraph",
      "depth":1,
      "text":"Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page. \n",
      "inlineStyleRanges":[],
      "inlineEntityRanges":[
         {
            "type":"LINK",
            "offset":83,
            "length":16,
            "data":{
               "target":"_self",
               "url":"/index.htm"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

With the above response, based on the `type` I'm creating a dynamic component called `ParagraphComponent` and below is the code

**ParagraphComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bw-paragraph',
  template: `<p #paragraph>{{ text }}</p>`
})
export class ParagraphComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('paragraph') paragraph: ElementRef;

  @Input()
  public text: string;

  constructor(
    private containerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private getTags:GenerateInlineTagsService,
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  contentOnCreate(values): void {
    if (values.depth === 1) {
      const content = this.getTags.getInlineTags(values);
      this.renderer.setProperty(this.paragraph.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', content);
    } else {
      this.text = values.text;
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, in the `"rjf"` object, we have `inlineEntityRanges` which tells that the `rjf.text` should have a `link` property inside it at the specific index using `offsest` & `length`. To achieve this i created a service `GenerateInlineTagsService`

```
export class GenerateInlineTagsService {

  constructor() { }

  getInlineTags(values) {
    let linkString = '';
    const content = values.text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
    if (values.inlineEntityRanges.length > 0) {
      const inlineData = values.inlineEntityRanges[0];
      if(inlineData.type === LINK) {
        linkString = this.getLinkText(inlineData.offset, inlineData.length, values.text);
        inlineData['linkString'] = linkString;
      }
      return content.replace(linkString, this.generateInlineTags(inlineData));
    }
    return content
  }

  getLinkText(offset, length, text: string) {
    return text.substr(offset, length);
  }

  generateInlineTags(elem: any): string {
    let result = '';
    switch (elem.type) {
      case LINK:
        result = `<a href='${elem.data.url.trim()}' target=${elem.data.target.trim()}' >${elem.linkString}</a>`;
        break;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

So with the above code, I could successfully convert `"rjf"` to angular view.

**So here come's the problem,**

In the `ParagraphComponent` I use the below code to bind the html string to angular view using `innerHtml` method,

```
this.renderer.setProperty(this.paragraph.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', content);
```

But my design got rejected because its I'm using `innerHTML` & it's not in angular way.

So What is not expected ?

1. Above `rjf` should be translated into angular view without using innerHTML
2. No SafeHtml or domsanitizer
3. No external library's like Jquery

What is expected ?

1. Way to create a template on the fly based on the remote response
2. Way to append routerLink to `p` based on the `offest` & `link`

I couldn't find another way, please need your guidance to overcome this

Comment: Look into [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to see if that will work for you. Also, look into [Ivy](https://blog.angularindepth.com/inside-ivy-exploring-the-new-angular-compiler-ebf85141cee1) to see if that might be something you want to use in the future (when it is released officially).

Comment: already using `Renderer2` and `Ivy` looks promising but since its not officially released I cant depend on it

Comment: I must have looked past the fact that you are using Renderer2, sorry. Not sure why this was rejected then. It's not like you are do direct DOM manipulation.